Control the draggable( object to X or Y when dragged
<div draggable="true" onDragOver={rowDragOver} onDrop={rowDrop} onDragStart={rowDragStart}>draggable</div>

It can be dragged by mouse control,
however now I want to control drag position only on X axis or Y axis,
I found out there is some libraris for this purpose.
However I would like to make this by normal javascript.
If make this ,I think I have to control the dragged(transparent) object when user dragging by mouse.
Maybe in this function, am I correct ? or how can I make this?
const rowDragOver = (e) =>{
  console.log("rowDragStart dragover:");
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}

